# ImproperlyConfigured at /posts/posts/in/uthi-group/comment/

Tags: python, django

So i have a project called star social project this project is similar to a socail media that you can post and create group but this project you can only post when you are in a group. So i get an error message that is not familiar to me which is on the title.The solution that i've tried is i added the get absolute urls to my posts models but i am still getting this error and now i'm very frustrate and i don't know what to do.So why im getting this error is because i'm trying to create a comment section and when i click the add comment that's when i get the error message. So i'm here to ask someone to help me because i'm not really familiar on this error and i'm just learning django for about 2 months now.[image: This is the actual error message]

posts models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from groups.models import Group
from misaka import html
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.message_html = html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'posts:single',
            kwargs={
                'username': self.user.username,
                'pk': self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:

        ordering = ['-created_at']

class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    # This is my solution on the error but im still getting that error message
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

groups models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import template
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from misaka import html
from django.urls import reverse

User = get_user_model()
register = template.Library()

class Group(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True, default="")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.description_html = html(self.description)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class GroupMember(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_groups', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:

        unique_together = ('user', 'group')
```

posts urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from posts import views

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='all'),
    path('by/<username>/', views.UserPost.as_view(), name='for_user'),
    path('by/<username>/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='single'),
    path('new/', views.CreatePost.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.DeletePost.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('posts/in/<slug>/comment/', views.AddComment.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
]
```

groups urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from groups import views

app_name = 'groups'

urlpatterns = [
    path('new/', views.CreateGroup.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('posts/in/<slug>/', views.SingleGroup.as_view(), name='single'),
    path('', views.ListGroups.as_view(), name='all'),
    path('join/<slug>/', views.JoinGroup.as_view(), name='join'),
    path('leave/<slug>/', views.LeaveGroup.as_view(), name='leave'),
]
```

posts views.py

```
class AddComment(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    model = Comment
    template_name = 'posts/comment_form.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

_post.html

```
<div class="media">
    <h3 class="mr-5"><a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=post.user.username %}">@{{ post.user.username }}</a></h3>

    <div class="media-body">
        <strong>{{ post.user.username }}</strong>
        <h5>{{ post.message_html|safe }}
            <time class="time"><a href="{% url 'posts:single' username=post.user.username pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.created_at }}</a></time>

            {% if post.group %}
                <span class="group-name">in <a href="#">{{ post.group.name }}</a></span>
            {% endif %}
        </h5>

        <h2>Comment...</h2>
        {% if not post.comments.all %}
            <h3>No comment yet...</h3>
            <a href="{% url 'posts:add_comment' slug=group.slug %}">Add Comment</a>
        {% else %}  
            <a href="{% url 'posts:add_comment' slug=group.slug %}">Add Comment</a>
            <br>
            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
            <br>
                {{ comment.text }}
            <br>
                <strong>
                    {{ comment.username }} -
                    {{ comment.created }}
                </strong>
            <br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <div class="media-footer">
            {% if user.is_authenticated and post.user == user and not hide_delete %}
                <a class="btn btn-simple" href="{% url 'posts:delete' pk=post.pk %}" title="delete"><span class="fa fa-remove text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="text-danger icon-label">Delete</span></a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

comment_form.html

```
{% extends 'posts/post_base.html' %}

    {% block post_content %}
        <h2>Add Comment</h2>

        <form id="commentForm" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think there might be an error with your settings.py file, because the ImproperlyConfigured exception is raised when Django is somehow improperly configured – for example, if a value in settings.py is incorrect or unparseable.

Comment: What should i do sir?

Answer (score 1):

This error is occur because you are trying to access slug in Comment model

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

and Comment model does not contain any column named as slug
There is two way you can handle this error
first you can create `slug` field in your `Comment` model and pass slug value from url.
Ans second is you can add id instead of slug like this
in your `urls.py`

```py
app_name = 'posts'
    
urlpatterns = [
   ....
   path('posts/in/<id>/comment/', views.AddComment.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
]
```

and inside your `posts models.py`

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    ........
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:add_comment', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

you are trying to get reverse of undefined means in your `groups` app there is no such type of url

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: @k3v1n can you provde your `AddComment` and where you want to redirect user after adding comment provide that also